# How can i excute a function after all ajax requests complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, declarative

I wanna execute a **JS Function** after all **Ajax** request in the page complete. 
But in the general way. Because i don't know how many Ajax Requests in the page. and i wanna make the code ***declarative*** to run even it the developer create an Ajax request in future.

let's take this code Example:

```
function ex(){
 alert("all Ajax requests have been sent");
}
```

Comment: This is not the same requirement. and the answers isn't enough. Because i can't use ( [$.when] ) if i don't know how many Ajax request in the page or if i wanna make it declarative " to make this function work even if the developer add more Ajax without edit on ( [$.when] ) function".